# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException , No qualifying bean of type [edu.sample.service.ItemService]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

It is spring boot application. i am getting below exception.how resolve it please help me 
    My Controller class is

```
import edu.sample.model.Item;
import edu.sample.service.ItemService;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.*")
@RestController
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="itemService")
    private ItemService itemService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllItems", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> getAllItems() {
        List<Item> items = itemService.getAllItems();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Item>>(items, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Service class  is

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {

    @Autowired
    ItemDAO itemDAO;

    @Override
    public String addItem(Item item) {
        return itemDAO.addItem(item);
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteItem(Integer id) {
        return itemDAO.deleteItem(id);
    } 

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Item item) {

    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
        return itemDAO.getAllItems();
    }

}
```

And DAO class

```
@Resource
public class ItemDAOImpl implements ItemDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public String addItem(Item item) {
        entityManager.persist(item);
        return item.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String deleteItem(Integer id) {
        String name=entityManager.find(Item.class, id).getName();
        entityManager.remove(id);
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Item item) {

    }

    @Override
    public List<Item> getAllItems() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from Item").getResultList();
    }

}
```

I get this exception message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'itemController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'itemService': No qualifying bean of type [edu.sample.service.ItemService] found for dependency [edu.sample.service.ItemService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=itemService)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [edu.sample.service.ItemService] found for dependency [edu.sample.service.ItemService]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=itemService)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to named `ItemServiceImpl` with your Qualifier `"itemService"` like this:

```
@Service("itemService")
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
    ...
```

Comment: It working fine,thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, the name of spring bean is taken from class name like `itemServiceImpl` for `ItemServiceImpl`.

With following declaration, you have a bean of type `ItemService` with name `itemServiceImpl`.

```
@Service
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
 /** ... */
}
```

However, since you're using `@Qualifier(value="itemService")`, you are trying to autowire bean by it's name. `ItemController` needs a bean with name `itemService` but the spring context doesn't have bean with that name and thus the `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "edu.*")
@RestController
public class ItemController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="itemService")
    private ItemService itemService;
    /* ... */
}
```

Now, to solve your problem, you can either give your `ItemServiceImpl` bean an explicit name like

```
@Service("itemService")
public class ItemServiceImpl implements ItemService {
 /** ... */
}
```

Another way is to let spring autowire `ItemService` bean by it's type rather than name by removing the `@Qualifier` annotation from `ItemController`. This approach works fine and is simple unless there are more than one bean of type `ItemService` in spring context.